# How to get the first attribute from an object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to build a traffic simulation; one of the classes is called lane, and it is representing the road.
It has these methods:

- A constructor __init__(length) that takes the length, i.e. the number of vehicles that can be on the lane. In the beginning, there are no vehicles in the lane.
- A method get_first() that returns the vehicle at the first position without deleting it. If the first place is empty, None is returned.
- A method remove_first() that returns and deletes the vehicle in the first place. If the place is empty, None is returned. The method makes no other changes to the Lane object.
- A method step() that moves all vehicles except the first one on the file (index 0) one position forward. A vehicle may only be moved if the next position is vacant. The move should take place from left to right, i.e. the vehicle on index 1 is moved first, then the vehicle on index 2 is moved, and so on.
- A method is_last_free() that returns True if the last place is free, otherwise False.
- A method enter(v) that places vehicle v at the end of the lane.
- A method number_in_lane() that returns the number of vehicles on the lane.
- The method __str__() that returns an appropriate string
  representation of the object.
  The goal is to get an output like this

```
[..........]
[.........N]
[........N.]
[.......NS.]
  out:  None
[......NS..]
[.....NS.S.]
[....NS.S..]
  out:  None
[...NS.S.S.]
[..NS.S.S..]
[.NS.S.S.S.]
  out:  None
[NS.S.S.S..]
[NSS.S.S.S.]
[NSSS.S.S..]
  out:  Vehicle(N, 34)
[SSS.S.S.S.]
[SSSS.S.S..]
[SSSSS.S.S.]
  out:  Vehicle(S, 0)
[SSSS.S.S..]
[SSSSS.S.S.]
[SSSSSS.S..]
  out:  Vehicle(S, 2)
[SSSSS.S.S.]
[SSSSSS.S..]
[SSSSSSS.S.]
  out:  Vehicle(S, 4)
[SSSSSS.S..]
Number in lane: 7
```

But what I got is this

```
Lane demonstration
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba30>, '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba30>, '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba30>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba00>, '.']
  out:  None
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba30>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba00>, '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba30>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba00>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b970>, '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba30>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba00>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b970>, '.']
  out:  None
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba30>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba00>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b970>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b910>, '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba30>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba00>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b970>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b910>, '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba30>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba00>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b970>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b910>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b8b0>, '.']
  out:  None
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba30>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba00>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b970>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b910>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b8b0>, '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba30>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba00>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b970>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b910>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b8b0>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b850>, '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba30>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba00>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b970>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b910>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b8b0>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b850>, '.']
  out:  None
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba30>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba00>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b970>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b910>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b8b0>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b850>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b7f0>, '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba30>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba00>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b970>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b910>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b8b0>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b850>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b7f0>, '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba30>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba00>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b970>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b910>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b8b0>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b850>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b7f0>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b790>, '.']
  out:  None
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba30>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba00>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b970>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b910>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b8b0>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b850>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b7f0>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b790>, '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba30>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba00>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b970>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b910>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b8b0>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b850>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b7f0>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b790>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b730>, '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba30>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba00>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b970>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b910>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b8b0>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b850>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b7f0>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b790>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b730>, '.']
  out:  None
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba30>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba00>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b970>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b910>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b8b0>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b850>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b7f0>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b790>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b730>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b6d0>, '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba30>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba00>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b970>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b910>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b8b0>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b850>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b7f0>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b790>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b730>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b6d0>, '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba30>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba00>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b970>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b910>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b8b0>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b850>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b7f0>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b790>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b730>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b6d0>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b670>, '.']
  out:  None
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba30>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546ba00>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b970>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b910>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b8b0>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b850>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b7f0>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b790>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b730>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b6d0>, <__main__.Vehicle object at 0x10546b670>, '.']
Number in lane: 11
```

There is also class called Vehicle. Its task is only to keep track of when the vehicle was created and where it is going. A vehicle does not need to know where it is, or to check traffic lights, or see other vehicles. Two instance variables are sufficient: named destination and time of creation.

The code is:

```
class Vehicle:
    """Represents vehicles in traffic simulations"""

    def __init__(self, destination, borntime):
        self.destination = destination


        self.borntime = borntime 
class Lane:
    "Represents a lane with (possible) vehicles"

    def __init__(self, length):

        self.length = length
        self.list = ['.'] * self.length

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.list)

    def enter(self, vehicle):
        return self.list.insert(-1, vehicle)

    def is_last_free(self):
        if self.list[-1] == '.':
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def step(self):
        pass

    def get_first(self):
        if self.list[0] == '.':
            return None
        else:
            return self.list[0]

    def remove_first(self):
        if self.list[0] == '.':
            return None
        else:
            x = self.list.pop(0)
            self.list.insert(0, '.')
            return x

    def number_in_lane(self):
        count = 0
        for i in self.list:
            if i != '.':
                count += 1
        return count



def demo_lane():
    """For demonstration of the class Lane"""
    a_lane = Lane(10)
    print(a_lane)
    v = Vehicle('N', 34)
    a_lane.enter(v)
    print(a_lane)

    a_lane.step()
    print(a_lane)
    for i in range(20):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            u = Vehicle('S', i)
            a_lane.enter(u)
        a_lane.step()
        print(a_lane)
        if i % 3 == 0:
            print('  out: ',
                  a_lane.remove_first())
    print('Number in lane:',
          a_lane.number_in_lane())


def main():
    """Demonstrates the classes"""
    print('\nLane demonstration')
    demo_lane()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I suggest to use a [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=deque#collections.deque) instead of a list for the Lane object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Lane` is a fixed length and there are bugs in the implementations using `insert` and `pop` methods that are making the lane longer.  I've implemented `step` below, fixed the display routines and the bugs:

```py
class Vehicle:
    '''Represents vehicles in traffic simulations
    '''
    def __init__(self, destination, borntime):
        self.destination = destination
        self.borntime = borntime 

    def __repr__(self):
        '''A verbose representation
        '''
        return f'Vehicle({self.destination}, {self.borntime})'

    def __str__(self):
        '''A simple representation
        '''
        return self.destination

class Lane:
    '''Represents a lane with (possible) vehicles
    '''
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.lane = ['.'] * length  # list is the name of a type, changed.

    def __str__(self):
        '''Lane representation
        '''
        return '[' + ''.join([str(s) for s in self.lane]) + ']'

    def enter(self, vehicle):
        self.lane[-1] = vehicle  # insert was making list longer

    def is_last_free(self):
        return self.lane[-1] == '.' # simplified instead of explicit T/F return.

    def step(self):
        '''Implementation of step
        '''
        for i in range(len(self.lane) - 1):
            if self.lane[i] == '.':  # if a spot is empty
                self.lane[i] = self.lane[i + 1] # move next spot forward
                self.lane[i + 1] = '.' # and clear next spot
        self.lane[-1] = '.' # clear the very last spot

    def get_first(self):
        if self.lane[0] == '.':
            return None
        else:
            return self.lane[0]

    def remove_first(self):
        x = self.lane[0]
        if x == '.':
            return None
        else:
            self.lane[0] = '.'  # simplified. no need for pop/insert
            return x

    def number_in_lane(self):
        return len(self.lane) - self.lane.count('.') # simplified

def demo_lane():
    '''For demonstration of the class Lane'''
    a_lane = Lane(10)
    print(a_lane)
    v = Vehicle('N', 34)
    a_lane.enter(v)
    print(a_lane)

    a_lane.step()
    print(a_lane)
    for i in range(20):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            u = Vehicle('S', i)
            a_lane.enter(u)
        a_lane.step()
        print(a_lane)
        if i % 3 == 0:
            print(f'  out: {a_lane.remove_first()!r}')  # !r uses __repr__ for display
    print('Number in lane:',
          a_lane.number_in_lane())

def main():
    '''Demonstrates the classes'''
    print('\nLane demonstration')
    demo_lane()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output (matches OP requirement):

```
Lane demonstration
[..........]
[.........N]
[........N.]
[.......NS.]
  out: None
[......NS..]
[.....NS.S.]
[....NS.S..]
  out: None
[...NS.S.S.]
[..NS.S.S..]
[.NS.S.S.S.]
  out: None
[NS.S.S.S..]
[NSS.S.S.S.]
[NSSS.S.S..]
  out: Vehicle(N, 34)
[SSS.S.S.S.]
[SSSS.S.S..]
[SSSSS.S.S.]
  out: Vehicle(S, 0)
[SSSS.S.S..]
[SSSSS.S.S.]
[SSSSSS.S..]
  out: Vehicle(S, 2)
[SSSSS.S.S.]
[SSSSSS.S..]
[SSSSSSS.S.]
  out: Vehicle(S, 4)
[SSSSSS.S..]
Number in lane: 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Your printing problems can be solved by two quick fixes.  In class Vehicle, provide a string converter:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return self.destination
```

Then, in class Lane, have the string converter do something useful instead of just blasting the list:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return '['+(''.join(str(i) for i in self.list))+']'
```

The rest of the trouble is because you haven't implemented `step` yet.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem:

```
class Vehicle:
    """Represents vehicles in traffic simulations"""

    def __init__(self, destination, borntime):
        self.destination = destination


        self.borntime = borntime

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Vehicle({self.destination}, {self.borntime})"

class Lane:
    "Represents a lane with (possible) vehicles"

    def __init__(self, length):

        self.length = length
        self.list = ['.'] * self.length

    def __str__(self):
        return "[" + "".join(it.destination if isinstance(it, Vehicle) else it for it in self.list) + "]"

    def enter(self, vehicle):
        return self.list.append(vehicle)

    def is_last_free(self):
        return self.list[-1] == '.'

    def step(self):
        self.remove_first()
        self.list.append(".")

    def get_first(self):
        if self.list[0] == '.':
            return None
        else:
            return self.list[0]

    def remove_first(self):
        x = self.list.pop(0)
        self.list.append('.')
        if x == '.':
            return None
        else:
            return x

    def number_in_lane(self):
        count = 0
        for i in self.list:
            if i != '.':
                count += 1
        return count



def demo_lane():
    """For demonstration of the class Lane"""
    a_lane = Lane(10)
    print(a_lane)
    v = Vehicle('N', 34)
    a_lane.enter(v)
    print(a_lane)

    a_lane.step()
    print(a_lane)
    for i in range(20):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            u = Vehicle('S', i)
            a_lane.enter(u)
        a_lane.step()
        print(a_lane)
        if i % 3 == 0:
            print('  out: ',
                  str(a_lane.get_first()))
            a_lane.step()
    print('Number in lane:',
          a_lane.number_in_lane())


def main():
    """Demonstrates the classes"""
    print('\nLane demonstration')
    demo_lane()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Haven't tested it though.
Will probably still need some more fixing - but that's up to you.